# Generating a maze in python and saving it into an image file resolves in to a black image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, maze

I split the code into two sections for easier viewing as it's little long. I have the following code that generates a maze in python and prints it into the terminal. This part of code works as expected:

```
import random
from PIL import Image

# The width and height of the maze
width = 30
height = 30

# The maze is represented as a 2D list of cells, where each cell is a dictionary with the following keys:
# "wall" - a set of directions ("N", "S", "E", "W") indicating which walls exist for the cell
# "visited" - a boolean indicating whether the cell has been visited during the maze generation process
maze = [[{"wall": {"N", "S", "E", "W"}, "visited": False} for j in range(width)] for i in range(height)]

# The start and end positions of the maze are always fixed
start = (0, 0)
end = (height-1, width-1)

# Set the start and end cells to be unvisited so that they are not included in the maze generation process
maze[start[0]][start[1]]["visited"] = True
maze[end[0]][end[1]]["visited"] = True

# Initialize a list of walls with all the walls in the maze
walls = []
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        if "N" in maze[i][j]["wall"]:
            walls.append((i, j, "N"))
        if "S" in maze[i][j]["wall"]:
            walls.append((i, j, "S"))
        if "E" in maze[i][j]["wall"]:
            walls.append((i, j, "E"))
        if "W" in maze[i][j]["wall"]:
            walls.append((i, j, "W"))

# Shuffle the list of walls
random.shuffle(walls)

# Initialize a disjoint-set data structure to keep track of connected cells
parent = {}
rank = {}

def make_set(cell):
    parent[cell] = cell
    rank[cell] = 0

def find(cell):
    if parent[cell] != cell:
        parent[cell] = find(parent[cell])
    return parent[cell]

def union(cell1, cell2):
    root1 = find(cell1)
    root2 = find(cell2)
    if root1 != root2:
        if rank[root1] > rank[root2]:
            parent[root2] = root1
        else:
            parent[root1] = root2
            if rank[root1] == rank[root2]:
                rank[root2] += 1

# Initialize the disjoint-set data structure with one set for each cell
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        make_set((i, j))

# Iterate through the list of walls and remove walls that would create a cycle
for wall in walls:
    i, j, direction = wall
    if direction == "N":
        ni, nj = i-1, j
    elif direction == "S":
        ni, nj = i+1, j
    elif direction == "E":
        ni, nj = i, j+1

    elif direction == "W":
        ni, nj = i, j-1
    if ni >= 0 and ni < height and nj >= 0 and nj < width and find((i, j)) != find((ni, nj)):
        maze[i][j]["wall"].discard(direction)
        maze[ni][nj]["wall"].discard("S" if direction == "N" else "N" if direction == "S" else "W" if direction == "E" else "E")
        union((i, j), (ni, nj))

# Print the maze
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        if (i, j) == start:
            print("S", end="")
        elif (i, j) == end:
            print("E", end="")
        elif "S" in maze[i][j]["wall"]:
            print("|", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
        if "E" in maze[i][j]["wall"]:
            print("_", end="")
        else:
            print(" ", end="")
    print()
```

Now when I try to generate an image using PIL, it just outputs a black image without the maze grid on a white background.

```
# Create an image with a white background
img = Image.new("RGB", (width*2+1, height*2+1), (255, 255, 255))
pixels = img.load()

# Color the cells and walls of the maze
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        if "S" in maze[i][j]:
            color = (0, 255, 0)
        elif "E" in maze[i][j]:
            color = (255, 0, 0)
        else:
            color = (0, 0, 0)
        for di in range(2):
            for dj in range(2):
                pixels[2*j+dj, 2*i+di] = color
        if "S" in maze[i][j]["wall"]:
            pixels[2*j+1, 2*i] = (0, 0, 0)
        if "E" in maze[i][j]["wall"]:
            pixels[2*j, 2*i+1] = (0, 0, 0)

# Save the image to a file
img.save("maze.png")
```

Any suggestions on how this could be fixed / improved?

Comment: maybe the pixel size is very large

Answer (score 0):

When you're initializing your list of walls, you check for N, S, E, W in maze[i][j]["wall"], but it looks like your image generation if and elif statements only check maze[i][j].

My guess is that it defaults to else, sets the color to (0,0,0), then the nested for loop fills in all the pixels with black. I see you do another check for S and E after that inside maze[i][j]["wall"], but it looks like that also just sets more pixels to black.

Hope this helped.